# Исчезновение объекта, когда он находится вне поля зрения камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать исчезновение объекта, когда он находится вне поля зрения камеры?

Comment: Ето способ оптимизации который мне тоже очень нужен, но к сажелению понятия не имею как ето сделать, поетому ни чем не могу вам помочь.

Comment: если вы вопрос касается оптимизации то посоветую почитать о dynamic occluded

Comment: точнее даже о Occlusion culling

Answer (score 1):

Нужно смотреть в сторону одного из путей:

OnWillRenderObject,

Renderer.isVisible,

Renderer.OnBecameVisible,

OnBecameInvisible

Реализация зависит от тебя.

Да и вопрос очень расплывчастый. Неясно как должно реагировать если видно только часть обьекта - он еще видимый камерой и или его уже считать невидимым?

По поводу как скрыть обьект - ну отключи его Renderer и он станет невидимым.

---

Можно дополнительно поискать информацию по запросам "unity is camera see object" или "Checking if gameobject is visible by camera"